# Cloud Run Python Script triggered by a Cloud Scheduler

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-scheduler

I am stuck trying to compose a Docker Build to Cloud Run. In testing I run the following DockerFile and schedule this in Cron using a bash script and `Docker run --rm -d` command

Dockerfile

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN CFLAGS=-O0 pip install --no-cache-dir -v -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "./Risklist.py" ]
```

Risklist.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    task = run_task()
    return task

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0',port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8080)))
```

I run the run_task() as a script that creates various files and folders and I have the fucntions above the app.route.

Is this correct as it doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: What makes you think it isn't working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Cloud Scheduler is showing as failed and when clicking on the app link its saying request 500 and not running

Comment: Ive got this working now but the GET task seems to take about 180 seconds just to run the script. Any way to make this faster? It should really be a POST but just need to get this to run the script as quick as possible.

Comment: Have you tried picking more RAM and CPU ? This usually make code execute faster.

Comment: Yep I added up to a 1GB of RAM and 2CPUs - to initialise the request is taking 180seconds then the script takes 500 or so seconds to run.

Comment: I think the only way to increase timeouts for Cloud Scheduler jobs is to use `gcloud` tool to create/update the job.

Comment: Thanks AhmetB I will take a look at it now.

Comment: Maybe you are hitting the 15 min maximum timeout from Cloud Run https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout